# HBase REST API Locking Rows

Tags: hbase

I am using HBase REST API from C#. I want to implement the Locking [rowlock in HBase Java API]
While retrieving the rows using REST API from C#. Help me on this issue....

Comment: I had c# client which will add and update the rows in HBase table using REST api.If two clients want to update the same row at a time what can i do. How can i implement locks on row

Answer (score 0):

First the row locking has been deprecated in [0.94](https://github.com/apache/hbase/commit/45b6a2f6adaf7729c165ebac155a7ebbe25d9881) and will be removed in [trunk](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-7315) soon, so you might not want to rely on it.

Secondly I don't think that REST server has a row locking api (see [here](https://github.com/apache/hbase/tree/0.94/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/rest) for the resources available).  Docs for the Rest server are located [here](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/rest/package-summary.html)

If you want to implement locks you can use check and put.  It's not available on rest, but it is available on [Thrift2](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/thrift2/ThriftHBaseServiceHandler.html)